# Running a ruby (class) more than once

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am trying to run minitest suite on sauce labs for each driver that I need.

I have a class that looks like:

```
class test_suite
    class test < MiniTest::Test

    def setup
        setup stuff
    end

    #test suite
    def test_1
    end
    def test_2
    end

    def teardown
    end
 end
end
```

The question is when I run the tests with a certain driver they work perfectly but when I try to run the tests twice, switching the driver between runs the tests only run on the last driver.

For example I have a

```
CHROME45 = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
CHROME45['version'] = "45.0"
CHROME45['platform'] = 'Windows 7'
```

and a firefox driver that looks similar. I want to run the tests and call the test class twice so that the runs would look like this (not actual output):

```
person:tests$ ruby Test_Runner.rb "test.rb" 
Started with run options --seed 22245

ChromeDriver
Test_Suite::Test
test1..etc                                          PASS     (16.44s)

FireFoxDriver
Test_Suite::Test
test1..etc                                         PASS     (16.44s)

Finished in 16.44553s
2 tests, 6 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

To sum it up. I want to run a set of tests once for every selenium/sauce driver that I create for testing without changing the driver manually between runs.

Answer (score 1):

Why not run them in parallel so you can run each driver test independent without the context of whether, or not, another driver test has been run? Perhaps use something like https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests.

Comment: I did try using the parallel_tests. I'm sorry my brain is mush right now from all the trial and error and googling I've been doing all day. I must have done something wrong. 

Do I need to be using a rake based test suite? 
Is there a way to hook this into minitest? I've tried the parallelization option that is available in minitest but I read that certain Ruby interpreters do not allow it. 

I've googled my brains out today I'll take another stab at it tomorrow but if you have any more info or an example you can link me to that would be greatly appreciated.